# Pandas previous month begin

Tags: datetime, pandas

Given a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c':[0,1,1,2,2,2],'date':pd.to_datetime(['2016-01-01','2016-02-01','2016-03-01','2016-04-01','2016-05-01','2016-06-05'])})
```

How to get the previous month begin for each date? The below doesn't work for 6/5 and there is some extra time portion.

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%Y%m") + pd.Timedelta(-1,unit='M') + MonthBegin(0)
```

**EDIT**

I have a workaround (2 steps back and 1 step forward):

```
(df['date']+ pd.Timedelta(-2,unit='M')+ MonthBegin(1)).dt.date
```

Don't like this. There should be something better.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can first subtract `MonthEnd` to get to the end of the previous month, then `MonthBegin` to get to the beginning of the previous month:

```
df['date'] - pd.offsets.MonthEnd() - pd.offsets.MonthBegin()
```

The resulting output:

```
0   2015-12-01
1   2016-01-01
2   2016-02-01
3   2016-03-01
4   2016-04-01
5   2016-05-01
```